# How can I save a CKAsset in Swift 2?

Tags: swift2, cloudkit

**Swift 2**

I am trying to save a small asset to CloudKit but not having much luck finding example code. The record is "Table1" and the asset is in the application bundle.  Any tips would be helpful. iOS9 Swift 2.

```
let audioPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("song-1", ofType: "mp3")!

let itemRecord:CKRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "Table1")
db.saveRecord(itemRecord) { (record:CKRecord?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
```

Comment: Where's your attempt at creating the `CKAsset` instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to create a CKAsset object. You could do that with something like:

```
let audioPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("song-1", ofType: "mp3")!
var file: CKAsset? = CKAsset(fileURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath))
```

After that you can just add it to your CKRecord using:

```
itemRecord.setValue(file, forKey: "AudioFile")
```